# MUI Alternative for AntD notification

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, axios, material-ui, antd

I have been using antD's `notification` api for some time. For my newest project, I am using MUI. I need to centralize the error handling for API requests, and I am using a common Axios instance to handle that.
There are `onSuccess` and `onError` methods to handle the scenarios. Currently, I am using console.log to display errors or success messages. With antD I had the following option.

```
notification.success({
    message: data.title,
    description: message,
    duration: 5,
  });
```

The notification could be triggered from anywhere in the application, not necessarily from a react component.
With MUI I am unable to do that. Is this possible with MUI? Can I work on a custom approach to display my error/ success messages in MUI Snackbars?

Comment: You can use redux, You can check this https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/centralized-error-handing-with-react-and-redux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research, I found out that there is no such implementation provided by MUI. What I am implementing now is an approach with Redux. https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/centralized-error-handing-with-react-and-redux
has given a good guide.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`notistack`](https://notistack.com/). It follows material design and really easy to use.